# VB.Net SQL Class Best way to get ExecuteScalar()

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I got the following Class to control SQL Server from Youtube Blogger VB ToolBox [Link to Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Z4BGEHD-JQ&list=PLt3JAHGUIUN_jE3umCixvfWJ2hJLsGZF_&index=10&t=2744s)

His code is

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class SQLControl
    Private ReadOnly DBCon As New SqlConnection("Server=XXXXXXXX;Database=XXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;")
    Private DBCmd As SqlCommand

    ' DB DATA
    Public DBDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable

    ' QUERY PARAMETERS
    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

    ' QUERY STATISTICS
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    ' ALLOW CONNECTION STRING OVERRIDE
    Public Sub New(ConnectionString As String)
        DBCon = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    End Sub

    ' EXECUTE QUERY SUB
    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
        ' RESET QUERY STATS
        RecordCount = 0
        Exception = ""

        Try
            DBCon.Open()

            ' CREATE DB COMMAND
            DBCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, DBCon)

            ' LOAD PARAMS INTO DB COMMAND
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))

            ' CLEAR PARAM LIST
            Params.Clear()

            ' EXECUTE COMMAND & FILL DATASET
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' CAPTURE ERROR
            Exception = "ExecQuery Error: " & vbNewLine & ex.Message
        Finally
            ' CLOSE CONNECTION
            If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub


    ' ADD PARAMS
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub

    ' ERROR CHECKING
    Public Function HasException(Optional Report As Boolean = False) As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Exception) Then Return False
        If Report = True Then MsgBox(Exception, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Exception:")
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

In this I would like to add an `ExecuteScalar()` call, so shall I add new `Sub` for it or there is a simpler way to do it. I look forward for your suggestion on best practices and validate above and below commands.

Thank you

```
Public DBMAX As String
Public Sub ExecMax(Query As String)
    DBCon.Open()
    DBCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, DBCon)
    Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))
    Params.Clear()
    DBMAX = DBCmd.ExecuteScalar()
    If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it work? There is a special site for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but its not this one.

Comment: Install Dapper. It's 2020; can't believe that people are still blogging about how to implement crappy roll-your-own-limited-functionality-data-access-layers when it (and EF, nHibernate, LINQ-to-sql, strongly typed datasets etc etc) has existed for years. I wish I had a dollar for every time I'd seen someone go back to absolute basics data access despite these techs existing.. http://dapper-tutorial.net

Comment: @DaleK Thank you for pointing to Code Review will use that, I am pretty new to this :)

Comment: @CaiusJard awesome will go through dapper tutorial as I am starting from scratch after my time in Fox Pro 25 years back, lot to catch up to.

Comment: if you're starting over (as I did a few years back) and if you've time, then look into Entity Framework and LINQ.  These weren't around when we were coding 'back in the day' but are worth learning now. Also, and it's a bigger ask, if you have the time and you're likely to be spending a lot of time coding, seriously consider learning c# instead of vb.net.  Both work, and I started with VB.net as it was closer to what I knew, but am now fully over to C# and it's worth it if you're going to be doing a lot of coding. If not, then stick with whatever works for you of course.

Comment: Thanks @JonRoberts , will look in to Entity Framework and LINQ, nice to know that some of my time with a break has started again and I am not alone :). I have just started as I had more time in lockdown, first thought of learning Python, but then came to more familiar Foxpro like :). Its not going to be lot of coding, but who know like you I may switch to C#. Good Luck and happy coding :)